# Missing labels in tokenized data set

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, sentiment-analysis, arff

I am implementing sentiment analysis, and when i tokenized my dataset.arff to use it as a training model, I have noticed that that is missing the label of "Positive"

the dataset.arff file Head:

relation SentimentAnalysis

@attribute text string
@attribute classValues {Positive,Negative,Neutral,'Very positive','Very negative'}

@data
'some text',Positive
'some text',Negative
'some text',Neutral
[...]

the tokenized data:

```
@relation 'SentimentAnalysis-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-R1-W5000-prune-rate-1.0-N0-stemmerweka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer-stopwords-handlerweka.core.stopwords.Null-M1-tokenizerweka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!\"'

@attribute classValues {Positive,Negative,Neutral,'Very positive','Very negative'}
```

all the words in the text as set as @attribute numeric

then i have the @data part

```
{0 Negative,20 1,220 1,228 [...] }
{0 Neutral,22 1,169 [...] }
{22 1,169 1,272 [...] }
```

########################################

this is just a a few lines example i have many more like that, i do not understand why is missing positive,

here my code for the tokenizer

```
public static void Tokenizer(){
           
            
            ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
            String filename = "dataset.arff";
            File file = new File(filename);
            
            //checking if the file exist

            if (file.exists()){
                try {
                    loader.setFile(new File(filename));
                    Instances data = loader.getDataSet();
                    if (data.classIndex() == -1){
                        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()- 1);
                    }

                    String[] options = new String[] {"-R", "1", "-W", "5000", "-prune-rate", "-1.0"};
                    StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
                    filter.setOptions(options);
                    filter.setInputFormat(data);
                    
                    Instances filteredData = Filter.useFilter(data, filter);
                    
                    File tokenizedFile = new File("tokenizeDataSet.arff");


                    ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
                    saver.setInstances(filteredData);
                    saver.setFile(tokenizedFile);
                    saver.writeBatch();

                    System.out.println("tokenized text saved properly");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error in reloading the Arff file:"+ e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
            }    
    }
```

I was expecting to have the Positive label in the tokenize data set too!

Answer (score 0):

They weren't lost. Nominal values at the first position merely get suppressed when using the sparse ARFF format. See the Weka wiki on the [sparse ARFF format](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/arff_developer/#sparse-arff-files).

Comment: So the Positive values it is just rapresented in some other way ?

Comment: Zeroes for numeric attributes and the first label for nominal atttibutes get omitted to save space ("sparse" format). If you look at your data in the Explorer (edit button) you will see the values being present. You can also use the SparseToNonSparse filter and then save it again in non-sparse format.